# Java Recursion Evaluation

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I am just working with a simple fibonacci recursion algorithm, but I've decided to tweak it to test my recursion knowledge further.

```
class fibonacci 
{ 
    static int fib(int n) 
    { 
    if (n <= 1) 
    return n; 
    int num = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    num += 1;
    return num;
    } 

    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
    int n = 4; 
    System.out.println(fib(n)); 
    } 
}
```

I am having difficulty as to how to evaluate this because I am getting 7 as the output, but when I evaluate it I am getting 4. Could someone explain step by step on what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with _evaluate_?

Comment: Just cheat and look at https://www.java67.com/2016/05/fibonacci-series-in-java-using-recursion.html

Comment: @Renato I mean why is it printing 7 when I think it should be printing 4

Comment: @Renato yes, that's the output, but I am having trouble figuring out why it is 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have the extra num +=1, for no reason I can see.  You're trying to correct, I think, for the only cases that don't go through that step.

According to your code:

```
fib(0) is 0
fib(1) is 1
fib(2) is fib(1) + fib(0) + 1 which is 2
fib(3) is fib(2) + fib(1) + 1 which is 4
fib(4) is fib(3) + fib(2) + 1 which is 7
```